# PHP cURL XML Response with single XML Tag

Tags: php, xml, curl, simplexml

I am using SimpleXML to load a response from an API call.  However, if the server returns an error, it only returns a single XML tag with the error message:

`<err>ERROR MESSAGE HERE</err>`

I'm currently using this code to parse the API response:

`$parsedresponse = simplexml_load_string($response);`

The $parsedresponse variable contains only the error message.  However, I need a way to check if the `<err>` tag is present so I know if there was an error.  I can't seem to figure out how to do this...

Thank you!

Comment: It might be easier to check the response for <err> before loading it into simple XML.

Comment: OK - that's what I was thinking to.  But I still can't quite figure out how to determine if it's in the raw response.  I've tried `if (!empty($response->err))` etc but that doesn't seem to do anything....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `err` tag is the root tag use the following condition to trace the error.

```
if ($parsedresponse->getName()=='err'){
    // got it
}
```

If its the first child use

```
if (isset($parsedresponse->err)){
    // got it
}
```

- negate the condition as necessary.

Comment: Thanks.  I just tried this code but PHP fails with this:  Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context

Comment: @Jason Oops. It'd be == instead of =. Writing from iPad, so missed it. See the update

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$xml = <<<EOF
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<err>ERROR MESSAGE HERE</err>
EOF;

$sxml = simplexml_load_string($xml);

if ($sxml->getName() != "err") print('not set');
else print('set');

?>
```